# Finding all the concrete classes that implements abstract class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class

Clicking "F3" on the `Change` class in eclipse,

```
Change change = refactoring.createChange(monitor);
```

I could open the Class.java.

```
public abstract class Change implements IAdaptable {
...
```

However, I need the concrete Java classes that implements the `Change` class. How can I find them in eclipse?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to see all implementations of the class.

Comment: Well, this is the faster way.

Answer (score 4):

> Go to `Windows` -> Open the `Outline View` -> Right click on the
>   required class -> Select `Open Type Hierarchy`.

This will open the window with the hierarchy involving that class.